# gSimplify not simplifying shapefile in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I'm unable to simplify a shapefile in R

Shapefile from here: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/Docs/Boundaries/Local_authority_district_(GB)_2014_Boundaries_(Generalised_Clipped).zip

```
library(tmap)
library(maptools)
library(ggmap)

England <- readOGR(dsn = "...")

#works fine
print(qtm(England, "LAD14CD", borders = NA, fill.title = "A-Level" )) 

# simplify the polygons
England<-gSimplify(England,tol=0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)

print(qtm(England, "LAD14CD", borders = NA, fill.title = "A-Level" ))
```

Gives an error of:

```
Error in process_fill(data, g$tm_fill, gborders, gt, gf, z = z + which(plot.order ==  : 
Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)
```

If you look at the UK dataobject you can see that it has changed from a Large Spatial polygonDataFrame to Large Spatial Polygons and dropped the @data

Instead, if you try to only simplify the polygons in the Shapefile:

```
England@polygons<-gSimplify(England@polygons,tol=0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)
```

It says that:

```
Error in gSimplify(England@polygons, tol = 0.01, topologyPreserve = TRUE) : 
cannot get a slot ("proj4string") from an object of type "list"
```

How can I simplify the polygons from a shapefile?

Comment: Where does `qtm` come from?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-nutshell.html

Comment: Thanks. Its always a good idea to add `library` calls to your questions when needed to run examples.

Comment: thanks, will do and have just edited this to show them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return from `gSimplify` is just the geometry, not the attributes, so you have to construct a new `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with the simplified geometry and the attribute data from the original:

```
> England2 <-gSimplify(England,tol=0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)
> England3 = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(England2, data=England@data)
```

I think the polygons are guaranteed to be in the same order, unless anything has been simplified away. Check `length(England2)` has the same number of rows as `England`, or match up the rows on an ID.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how to do that ID matching.

Comment: i tried hard to do the mentioned ID matching but i cannot figure out how to line things up. the IDs that come out of gSimplify seem to just be 1, 2, 3, ... N, regardless of how many polygons are dropped