# Simplifying polygons in rgeos and maintaining data in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-sp, rgeo

## Background

I'm interested in simplifying polygons with use of the [**`gSimplify`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-22/topics/gSimplify) function available through the [`rgeos`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos) package.

## Reproducible example

A reproducible example can be generated with use of the code below:

```
# Data sourcing -----------------------------------------------------------

# Download an read US state shapefiles
tmp_shps <- tempfile()
tmp_dir <- tempdir()
download.file(
    "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_state_20m.zip",
    tmp_shps
)
unzip(tmp_shps, exdir = tmp_dir)

# Libs
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)

# Read
us_shps <- readOGR(dsn = tmp_dir, layer = "cb_2014_us_state_20m")

# Simplified --------------------------------------------------------------

# Simplifiy
us_shps_smpl <- gSimplify(spgeom = us_shps,
                          tol = 200,
                          topologyPreserve = TRUE)
```

### Preview

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(us_shps_smpl, main = "Simplified")
plot(us_shps, main = "Original")
```

[image: Simplified and original polygons]

## Problem

In addittion to simplifying polygons the [**`gSimplify`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-22/topics/gSimplify) function changed classes of the resulting object:

```
>> class(us_shps)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
>> class(us_shps_smpl)
[1] "SpatialPolygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

>> names(us_shps)
[1] "STATEFP"  "STATENS"  "AFFGEOID" "GEOID"    "STUSPS"   "NAME"     "LSAD"     "ALAND"    "AWATER"  
>> names(us_shps_smpl)
 [1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19"
[21] "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39"
[41] "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "47" "48" "49" "50" "51"
```

### Questions

- How can I safely reattached the data that was initially available in the original object and transform the resulting `SpatialPolygons` object to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`
- I reckon that one approach would simply involve [attaching data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652472/1655567);but this depends on the order of elements not changing. Are there any other better approaches (ideally preserving initial object class)?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/  they can help you for surely

Comment: @AndreElrico I post on [gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) periodically but to my mind this question is more concerned with how the the `gSimplify` handles `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` class, less with quantitative geography aspect of the problem. I reckon it's not a clear cut but I presume that a lot of people who follow [tag:rgeos] and [tag:gis] look at both boards.

Comment: just wanted to make sure you're aware of that site :-)

Comment: Yes, you can reattach the data using `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(us_shps_smpl, us_shps@data)`. Do you have any example where the order of elements changed after `gSimplify`?

Comment: Answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34827535/8449629) may be of relevance.

Comment: @Z.Lin No, I don't and I didn't presume that it changes. I was hoping that someone here will confirm that it does not change, which seems to be the case.

Comment: @Z.Lin Worth adding, in my production code the should have `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` `match.ID = FALSE` argument to avoid failing on mismatched IDs.

Comment: Are you wedded to `rgeos`? Otherwise, I believe `sf::st_simplify()` could help you out here.

Comment: @coletl Thanks, happy to consider other packages. Feel free to make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sf` package is based entirely on data frames, so its geometry manipulations always preserve the data attached to each feature. The package hasn't caught up with all the standard spatial packages in R yet, but it's fairly easy to go back and forth between `sf` and `sp` objects when you need more functionality.

Here, `st_simplify()` does the work, but you'll need to project your polygons first:

```
library(sf)

# Download and read example data
tmp_shps <- tempfile()
tmp_dir <- tempdir()
download.file(
  "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_state_20m.zip",
  tmp_shps
)
unzip(tmp_shps, exdir = tmp_dir)

us_shps <- st_read(paste(tmp_dir, "cb_2014_us_state_20m.shp", sep = "/"))

# st_simplify needs a projected CRS
us_shps_merc <- st_transform(us_shps, 3857)
simple_us_merc <- st_simplify(us_shps_merc)

# Change back to original CRS
simple_us <- st_transform(simple_us_merc, st_crs(us_shps))

# Change to sp object, if you like
simple_us_sp <- as(st_zm(simple_us), "Spatial")
```

Comment: i found that if st_simplify drops some polygons, the geometry column will become an empty list in those rows ("list()"). those "empty geometry" rows will have to be removed before as(.,"Spatial") is applied or an error appears